# Does the equation $\vec{E}=\sigma \vec{J}$ holds in perfect conductors?

Tags: electromagnetism

In perfect conductors, $\vec{E}=0$,
so if the relation $\vec{E}=\sigma 
 \vec{J}$ is to hold, then I should have $\vec{J}$ equals zero as well which isn't the case, so the aforementioned relationship can't hold in perfect conductors right?

Comment: 1/ In a perfect conductor, $\sigma=0$. 2/ Traditionally, the relation is written $\vec{E}=\rho 
 \vec{J}$, with $\rho$ the resistivity and $\sigma=1/\rho$ the conductivity.

Comment: In perfect conductors $\sigma=∞$

Comment: Yes, read my comment again.

Comment: For a perfect conductor $\rho = 0$, and with  $E=\rho\,J \Rightarrow 0=0 \times J$, $J$ can be any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are confusing conductivity $\sigma$ and resistivity $\rho$.
The [microscopic Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) is usually written as
$$\vec{J}=\sigma\vec{E} \tag{1}$$
or equivalently,
$$\vec{E}=\rho\vec{J} \tag{2}$$
with $\rho=1/\sigma$.

In a perfect conductor the resistivity is zero ($\rho=0$),
or equivalently, the conductivity is infinite ($\sigma=\infty$).
Now consider a non-zero current-density $\vec{J}$ in a perfect conductor.
Then, from (1) you can conclude $\vec{E}=\vec{0}$
(because $\infty\cdot 0$ can be everything). And also from (2)
you can conclude $\vec{E}=\vec{0}$, as it should be.